# Use Tweenmax from cdn with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, gsap

I'm loading TweenMax from cdnjs and using the `externals` option of webpack, however, I'm unable to make this work in my vue webpack setup. I'm getting `TweenMax is not defined`

[image: Untitled-1]

Loading script

`wp_enqueue_script( 'tweenmax', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.3/TweenMax.min.js', array(), false, true );`

webpack.dev.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app.js'),
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    filename: '[name].app.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].app.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery',
    TweenMax: 'TweenMax',
  }
}
```

.vue file

```
import TweenMax from 'TweenMax'

$(el).each(function(i){
        TweenMax.from($(this), time, {
          opacity: 0,
          x: 0,
          y: that.random(-200, 200),
          z: that.random(500, 1000),
          // scale: .1,
          delay: i * delay,
          yoyo: true,
          repeat: -1,
          repeatDelay: time * 10,
          ease: Power1.easeOut
        });
      });
```

Comment: Could it be the casing of tweenmax in the loading script?

Comment: No, that's just the handle name in wordpress for references

Comment: Have you validated in the network tab that the page is definitely loading TweenMax?  Is it possible that TweenMax is loading after your main script starts executing?

Comment: That was the silly mistake I was making. Thank you for your help.